# Run Neo4j queries from Cypher files in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am using the official [Neo4j Javascript driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver) to connect with my database. I want to run queries directly from `.cypher` files because writing them as strings is much more error-prone.

I don't want to read the file using `fs`, as it would consume unnecessary resources. I want to `import` the file as I do with a JSON file (at compile time)

How can I do that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp

Comment: You can just import the cypher file using fs.readFile() or something, and execute the query

Comment: I don't want to read the file, I want to just import that file

Comment: Does the database has access to those files?

Comment: @TomažBratanič What exactly do you mean? Those files are in the NodeJS project and the database is just running remotely...

Comment: I am afraid it can't be done in a straightforward manner, using require function or import keyword. The best we can do is basically store the queries in a JSON file, with the key being the cypher file name, and the value is the actual query. Because even if we try to extend some base node js module, it will be via fs only. So, we are back to square one there

Answer (score 0):

You could use the approach that is used in [graphacademy](https://graphacademy.neo4j.com) for test fixtures.

There a js file is imported that holds the fixtures as javascript objects.

You can do the same just with Cypher queries.

See:

https://github.com/neo4j-graphacademy/app-nodejs/blob/main/test/fixtures/movies.js

```
import { goodfellas, popular } from '../../test/fixtures/movies.js'
```

https://github.com/neo4j-graphacademy/app-nodejs/blob/main/src/services/movie.service.js#L1

Comment: Thank you, however, what I really want is code completion and live-checking. In other words, I need pure .cypher files that my IDE will recognize and then import them as strings inside my JS/TS program.